# Clear screen for MYSQL command line client 3

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql5

I tried many of the commands clear the screen in mysql command line on windows but not working...
commands are

clear screen;
cl scr;
cls;
system clear;
system clear screen;
ctrl + l;
tell me the solution if any body have idea in this topic....

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I clear the screen in the MYSQL 3 command line client?

Unfortunately this feature is not available in the Windows version..

There is a bug report [Bug #58680 Windows Clear Screen Command](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680) raised (in 2010). It is marked as open (status minor).

See StackOverflow question [How do I clear the mysql screen, opened through the MySQL Command Line Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514914/how-do-i-clear-the-mysql-screen-opened-through-the-mysql-command-line-client) for more discussion about this.

---

#### Bug #58680 Windows Clear Screen Command

> Description: I have a customer who asked for a clear screen command
> line for MySQL on Windows. After researching, we found out that !
> clear, system clear or Crtl+L don't work for windows.
>
> I think it would be important to have this type of command available
> for Windows.
>
> ...
>
> Thank you for the problem report. Indeed, **this feature is not
> available on Windows.**

Source [Bug #58680 Windows Clear Screen Command](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680)